# cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called

Tags: ios, swift

I have a storyboard which contains `UIViewController` which has `UITableview` and `UITableViewCell`, everything is hooked up properly and I have put all the required code for UIViewController.

When I run the app in the simulator one of the datasource function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called but `numberOfRowsInSection` is called

- "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int" is called
- But "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" **IS NEVER CALLED**

Below is my code for view controller:

```
import UIKit

class DVViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{

    @IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView?
    var tableData = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    let kCellID = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView?.delegate = self;
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self;

        //load cell
        self.tableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCellID);
        self.tableView?.reloadData();
    }

    //MARK: Tableview delegates
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.tableData.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
       //var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellID)
        let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell (style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kCellID);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called?

Comment: Have you breakpointed and ensured that nothing is being released by ARC? At this point in time, you cannot rely on anything to be correct with Swift and the new Xcode Beta. Memory retaining, outlets, optionals have been changing with each update. Swift is a rapidly changing language, and frankly it's pretty silly asking people on Stack Overflow these questions until Swift is out of Beta. Try the same logic in Objective-C, if it works, you know where you're problem is.

Comment: I recreated the project with objective c and still the have the same issue, "numberOfRowsInSection" is called but not the "cellForRowAtIndexPath".

Comment: If all you're outlets are connected in Objective C, and the code matches that above, and there's no weird state that you're not displaying where the tableView could be set to nil, and tableData is returning the correct count, then you may want to test this using Xcode 5 and see the results. If this indeed works using Objective-C in Xcode 5 and not 6 you've confirmed it's an Xcode 6 problem. If not, it's your code.

Comment: TheGamingArt, Will try that tomorrow and will update, thanks.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, start this project as a "Master Detail" project, and then replace a controller that was derived from a UITableViewController with your current one, that isn't? (If you go have a look at the properties of your view controller in Interface Builder, what type does it say it is under the Quick Help tab in the inspector?)

Comment: No, it's a single view Application and it does not use UITableViewController. Although I had tried creating "single view Application"  using UITablevViewController which seems to work OK but I wanted to use UIViewController with UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource as it give me control in terms of UI which is not the case with UITableViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did, uninstalled Xcode 5 & 6 both the  reinstalled Xcode 6 only, Ran the project and it WORKED. After 2 days of debugging its the reinstall which did the trick.

Comment: Uh, you do realize they updated Xcode 6 to the GM version right?..... When they announced the iPhone 6

Comment: Thanks, I did download on the same day it was release :)

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked your code, it works.
Check to see whether or not `numberOfRowsInSection` is called. if not check the connection in [storyboard](http://i62.tinypic.com/r9o5fr.png).

Comment: Yup, works for me. And a missing connection of the IBOutlet in the storyboard is the only think I can think of that would produce the problem, too.

Comment: I thought of that too first that's not a problem. Outlet is hooked up correctly if it wasn't then none of the datasource methods would be called but "numberOfRowsInSection" is called but not the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

func viewDidLoad(){

super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.dataSource = self

tableView.delegate = self

}

}